# Matching CryptoJS.SHA256() with hashlib.sha256() for a JSON

Tags: javascript, python, json, sha256, cryptojs

As a part of IEFT standard, I need to hash the body of a JSON request.

I have a reference code in JS that is known to produce the right hash, but now I'm stuck with matching the result in Python.

The JSON body:

```
body = {"description":"Test ticket"}
```

The JS code:

```
bodyHash = CryptoJS.SHA256(body).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)
```

Please note it's not `JSON.stringify(body)`! The "correct" hash (the one I'm looking to match):

```
TqXFCKZWbnYkBUP4/rBv1Fd3e+OVScQBZDav2mXSMw4=
```

The Python solution should be along the lines of:

```
body_hash = base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(repr(body).encode('utf-8')).digest()).decode('ascii')
```

Which produces something different:

```
z0RpYmKAIfVibpSLJx/iRDZaNHJkJ2+rcenc1KEEAUw=
```

Is there even a way to match those hashes? How the JS object is hashed in CryptoJS?

Comment: I think that in JavaScript you're hashing the value of `body.toString()` in JavaScript, which is probably just `'[object Object]'`. I think you'll find you get the same hash no matter what the object you pass in looks like.

Comment: Thanks so much @Paulpro, that's indeed so. So I need to question the validity of the "reference" given by the client...

Comment: Also from the Python side, `repr(body)` will not actually produce a valid JSON in many cases (due to `str` values being quoted with single quotes).  Please consider using [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) from the JavaScript side and [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) from Python, **while also** keeping in mind that the order which the key/values being dumped may differ between the two.